# How not to quit processes started by your own process when exiting

Tags: java, process, runtime

I use

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(anotherProgramPath);
```

And when I exit my program the other program exits too. Can someone tell me how to fix this annoying bug

Comment: Google "detach child process from parent". The solutions are platform-specific, Java does not provide for this.

Comment: Annoying it may be, but a bug - it isn't.